# How can I change the font of Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE?

Tags: windows, netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

I have tried to go to the netbeans.conf file but when I try to edit netbeans_default_options to include --fontsize and save the file it gives me an error of "Access to the 'filepath' has been denied"

I am logged in an administrative account if that make any difference.

Any idea on what might be causing the problem?

Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: why dont you change using tools->option->font&colors ?

Comment: I tried but it changes the text size, that's not the issue. The link shows how my screen looks  [Screen](http://imgur.com/6tfUnWS)

Comment: link? i dont see any link

Comment: http://imgur.com/6tfUnWS

Comment: ooh. that text. sorry, i misunderstand your question as text in editor. Try this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2623670